# How to create create subtitle using a text editor?

Tags: utf-8, notepad, subtitle

I want to translate a SubRip subtitle file from English to my language. I know there exists free software(s) such as Subtitle Workshop which can be used for this kind of purposes. However, they reduce my speed due to absence of good shortcut keys. So, I prefer to use a simple text editor such as Notepad. However, when I save my translation using utf-8 encoding, it works for me, but Subtitle workshop opens it such that sentences are not rendered using utf-8 encoding and nothing can be read properly (some werid characters appear) but it is OK in my video player. Is anything wrong with my work? Any help? I want to save my subtitle in text editor and the output can be opened in a software such as Subtitle Workshop as the same as other subtitles.

Comment: Instead of using simple Notepad, you can use Notepad++ or Atom or SublimeText. They are free and open source and much more sophisticated.

Comment: Excuse me, my problem is not the text editor itself. The problem is where the output could not be opened in Subtitle Workshop as a standard subtitle could.

Comment: What is wrong with my encoding?

Comment: Notepad clears out any encoding, font preferences etc that you might have in your text.

Comment: No, Dear Sampada, it can maintain my encoding. I can choose encoding in save dialog. My problem is with opening it in Subtitle Workshop and other subtitle editing software(s). I don't know why they do not render using utf-8 encoding. However, any other text editing tools show it properly. I think i should not use utf-8 as my encoding.